# Extracting vectors from Structure in header file

Tags: c++

This is the header file in question:

```
namespace osc {
using namespace gdt;

  struct TriangleMesh {
    std::vector<vec3f> vertex;
    std::vector<vec3f> normal;
    std::vector<vec2f> texcoord;
    std::vector<vec3i> index;

    // material data:
    vec3f              diffuse;
  };

  struct Model {
    ~Model()
    { for (auto mesh : meshes) delete mesh; }

    std::vector<TriangleMesh *> meshes;
    //! bounding box of all vertices in the model
    box3f bounds;
  };

  Model *loadOBJ(const std::string &objFile);
}
```

I have successfully been able to use this header file to import an `.obj` of the 3D model in my main C++ code using the `loadOBJ()` function described in the header. I now want to operate on the vertices of that model. From the looks of it, the vertex points are in the structures defined in the header file. How do I extract these vertex vectors from the structure (and display them)?

Comment: Given an instance of `TriangleMesh`, do you know how to extract `vertex`?

Comment: That's what I am trying to figure out haha. I understand if vertex was type int but I am having difficulty figuring out what to do since its a vector type. Thanks

Comment: Try: `std::vector<vec3f> vertices = my_triangle_mesh.vertex;`.

Comment: You dont know how to iterate through a vector?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thank you for that. Makes more sense when you put it that way. I think was overly confusing myself. I ended up using the answer Remy gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`loadOBJ()` gives you a pointer to a `Model` object.

`Model` has a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (a dynamic array) member named `meshes` that holds pointers to `TriangleMesh` objects.

`TriangleMesh` has a `std::vector` member named `vertex` holding `vec3f` objects.

You can iterate the various `vector`s like this:

```
osc::Model *model = osc::loadOBJ(...);
if (!model) ... // error handling

for (auto&& mesh : model->meshes)
{
    cout << "vertex:\n";
    for (auto&& vtx : mesh->vertex)
    {
        cout << "x=" << vtx.x << ", y=" << vtx.y << "z=" << vtx.z << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";

    // repeat for mesh->normal, mesh->texcoord, mesh->index, etc...
}

delete model;
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked and was very helpful! Your explanation also cleared up my confusion regarding how the 2 structures in the .h file worked. And thank you for editing my initial post too, I now have a better idea of how to ask questions on this platform too!

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector` is a dynamic array in c++

if you want to enumerate

```
 std::vector<vec3f> vertex;
```

you do

```
 for(auto vert: vertex)
 {
    // here vert is of type vec3F
  }
```

you can also access it like an array

```
 vec3f v2 = vertex[2];
```

of course you must make sure vertex has at least 2 elements. You can find the length with `vertex.size()`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I had already tried the first method you mentioned. Remy's answer below is what I ended up using and it worked.

Comment: @RD4235 remy is the man to trust :-)

Comment: Hahah roger that